# How can I regexp match a URL from an onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, regex, events, keyboard

I am using this RegExp to match a URL

```
 reMatchUrl = /(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?/i
```

But how do I modify the RegExp to match a URL in a `input[type=textarea]` element as it is being typed or copy/pasted? (i.e. from onKeyUp event)

The challenge is to wait until the URL is complete (check for a trailing space?), and also correctly process a copy/paste block that includes a URL. But if the string ends with a url, there will not be a trailing space...

example:

```
// match only the url in the string, 
// recognizing that the URL is complete
string = "hey, check this out http://www.something.com/this/is/cool?a=b"
found = string.match(reMatchUrl)
url = found && found[0]
// url = "http://www.something.com/this/is/cool?a=b"

// does NOT match the url in the string because the user 
// has NOT finished typing
string = "hey, check this out http://www.something.com/this/is/coo"
found = string.match(reMatchUrl)
url = found && found[0]
// url = null
```

Comment: So you want to record the keys pressed with a keyup into a string, then once that string is complete you want to match with it? And whats this about preceding text?

Comment: u need this as a native javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I know how to user the JS events, what I need is a RegExp that discards additional text and recognizes the end of a typed URL string.

Answer (score 0):

This works, with pure JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <label for="url">set an url:</label>
    <input type="text" id="url">
    <br><br>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
        // regex string
        var reMatchUrl = '(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?';
        // build regex matched
        var regx = new RegExp(reMatchUrl, 'i');

        // add event listener on input
        document.getElementById('url').addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
            // get the text in the input
            var input = document.getElementById('url').value;

            // check for a match
            var match = input.match(regx);

            // update html
            if (match) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  'valid';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  'not valid';
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it listens for Key Up events on the input, then updates the state if the value of the input matches your regex.

Comment: It is true but it listen to input not url

Comment: question is unclear, but I don't see why anybody would want to listen to location.href as it's being typed.

Comment: I want to listen to a input[type=textarea] as it's being typed.